# Processing multiple csv files with Generative AI on Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, large-language-model, google-generativeai, google-gemini

I need a way to pass in multiple csv files into Google's Generative AI API and have them analyzed. I'm just looking for a JSON output.

Is there a way to just pass the files into the API to be analyzed? Or do I need to turn the csv into JSON and do multiple requests so I don't exceed the token limit?

I've tried using the sandbox enviroment on Google Cloud but it only accepts videos and images. I've also tried passing in a large amount of JSON but it seems to break things.

Comment: Your post is too vague. What is the data? Which API are you using? Which model are you using? What analysis are you expecting? What kind of result? In general, data must be transformed for Vertex AI. The data structure must match the data the model was trained on. However, I have no idea what you are starting with or the desired result. Edit your post and provide the details necessary so that it can be answered.